# python: How do you scrape a webpage with bad HTML tags?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have used beautiful soup to scrape a webpage with a table in it. For most pages it scrapes the webpage fine but on some pages a bad HTML tag messes up the response. The text should have a link (I don't need the link) but it does not, the person who coded it did leave a stray `</a>` without ever opening the tag. This results in the response from both requests and urllib2 to be cut off early.

An example of the HTML I am on about:

`<tr><td><small>03 Feb 2015 3:21:26 AM</small></td><td >Text with no link</a></td>`

That `</a>` tag cuts off the table in the response but does not show up, is there any way I can request for the HTML of the page and ignore all `</a>` tags only (as I need the other tags)? Or ignore all strings of the form `link</a>` (as every occurrence is on a specific string).

I think I could do it by getting the raw HTML but if I user urllib or requests they don't give me the raw HTML they cut off the table because of the tag and don't show the stray tag causing it.

Solved: the raw HTML can be obtained using the method as shown here [How to print raw html string using urllib3？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257912/how-to-print-raw-html-string-using-urllib3) , response normally prints the raw html but in this case it did not due to the bad tag, but this shows the raw HTML even with bad tags.

Comment: Have you tried using [html5lib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html5lib)? This parser is much more forgiving than the standard parsers, and will correct html errors.