# error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode charactor

Tags: python

I'm a python beginner. I wrote code as following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.google.com"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.find_all("a")
for link in links:
    print(link.text)
```

When run this .py file in windows powershell, the print(link.text) causes the following error.

```
error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode charactor '\xbb' in position 5: 
illegal multibyte sequence.
```

I know the error is caused by some chinese characters, and It seem like I should use 'decode' or 'ignore', but I don't know how to fix my code. Help please! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to display those special chars:
You can ignore them by:

```
print(link.text.encode(errors="ignore"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the string in `utf8`.

```
for link in links:
    print(link.text.encode('utf8'))
```

But better approach is:

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text.encode("utf8"), "html.parser")
```

To understand more about the problem you are facing, you should look at this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3218048/5352399).