# what's the matter with sublime text3 and python?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I got a problem when using sublime.
I have several python's envs created by virtualenv,now I want to run my project with one of these env,so I built a new system with the settings below

```
{
    "cmd": ["E:/virtualenv_python36/Scripts/python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

but I got an exception when using this system

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kuo\Desktop\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(rps.read().decode())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\xbb' in position 27237: illegal multibyte sequence
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['E:/virtualenv_python36/Scripts/python.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\kuo\\Desktop\\test.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\kuo\Desktop]
[path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;D:\Python36\Scripts\;D:\Python36\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\kuo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

here is my test code

```
import urllib.request

rps = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.baidu.com')
print(rps.read().decode())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character: illegal multibyte sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218014/unicodeencodeerror-gbk-codec-cant-encode-character-illegal-multibyte-sequen)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Python interpreter tries to load the *result* of your `print` invocation, which is a webpage in Chinese. Possibly it tries to show you the output.

I'm not sure the encoding of the page and the encoding of your file / buffer are the same. I'd rather use an explicit argument to `.decode()`.

(Also, consider using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/).)

Comment: thanks for your suggestions,but it's same to any other sites,also requests will get the same exception.I think there is something wrong with my settings of sublime.

Comment: and when I switch to the original python system of sublime to ran the code,this exception was no longer exists.