# python to print unicode special charaters

Tags: python-3.x, python-unicode

I am trying to print Unicode 220e:
https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/220e/index.htm

It says the python sources code should be

```
print(u"\u220E")
```

Then I will get this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\u220e' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Is there a way to fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character: illegal multibyte sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218014/unicodeencodeerror-gbk-codec-cant-encode-character-illegal-multibyte-sequen)

Comment: Does your output terminal really use `gbk` as its native encoding? Then the error message is correct: there is no valid value it can convert U+220E to for your terminal to display. ∎

Comment: … as proof of this I ran your code snippet from inside Sublime Text (its stdout supports UTF8 and so it is capable of displaying every valid Unicode character). The result is, as I already expected: `∎`

Comment: @usr2564301 I see! My terminal does not use gbk. So the problem is my output terminal instead of the code